# piece of string

Tags: javascript, string

Hy guys

I have a string containing:

> '09:29'

. How can I return the

> '29'

and eliminate the '09:'?

Thks!

Comment: Are you certain of the length or would you have to search for the : ?

Comment: It's two numbers + ":" + two numbers. 5 characters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var str = '09:29';
var parts = str.split(':');
alert(parts[1]);
```

Comment: i think using regex in split will be faster. like this: split(/\:/) because i didnt use 'g' (global) attribute and this one will stop seeking delimiter after first found

Answer (score 6):

You can [`.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string into an array and [`.pop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Pop) the result (last member) pretty cleanly, like this:

```
var str = '09:29';
return str.split(':').pop();
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/QQM3W/).

Comment: Nice to see that mark near your name. Congratz on becoming the moderator ;-)

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to use Regular expressions (see [this demo](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html)). I believe this code should do the trick (not tested).

```
var re = new RegExp("\b\d+:(\d+)\b");
var m = re.exec(yourString);
if(m !=  null) {
     alert("Match: "+ m[1]);
}
```

Comment: there is just one second between your answer and mine :)

Answer (score 2):

regex version:

```
return /\d{2}\:(\d{2})/.exec('09:29')[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   var time = "09:29"
   var bits = time.split(":")
   var minutes = bits[1]
```

Comment: this will throw an undefined value exception for bits :) (edit: comment was posted just before this answer edited)

Comment: I think that was before I corrected it :) Thanks for the report, anyway.